# WHERE CASE returning multiple rows

Tags: sql, case

I want this query to return only one row. I have put there WHEN clauses of the CASE statement in the order they would most likely occur in, so the most likely TRUE statement will always be evaluated first. However, it seems like every WHEN statement is being evaluated before the query finishes, despite it finding multiple TRUE statements.

```
SELECT To_Char(T.PRFINISH, 'DD/MM/YY') FINISH,
       T.PRNAME  
FROM  PRTASK T
      LEFT OUTER JOIN INV_INVESTMENTS ON T.PRPROJECTID = INV_INVESTMENTS.ID
WHERE T.PRNAME = CASE 
                    WHEN (T.PRNAME = 'Concept Tech PEP Meeting Date' AND T.PRSTATUS != 2) THEN 'Concept Tech PEP Meeting Date'
                    WHEN (T.PRNAME = 'Concept BRU Meeting Date' AND T.PRSTATUS != 2) THEN 'Concept BRU Meeting Date'
                    WHEN (T.PRNAME = 'End of Concept Phase' AND T.PRSTATUS != 2) THEN 'End of Concept Phase'                                                                                                                 
                    WHEN (T.PRNAME = 'Evaluate Tech PEP Meeting Date' AND T.PRSTATUS != 2) THEN 'Evaluate Tech PEP Meeting Date'
                    WHEN (T.PRNAME = 'Evaluate BRU Meeting Date' AND T.PRSTATUS != 2) THEN 'Evaluate BRU Meeting Date'
                    WHEN (T.PRNAME = 'Evaluate TSC Meeting Date' AND T.PRSTATUS != 2) THEN 'Evaluate TSC Meeting Date'
                    WHEN (T.PRNAME = 'End of Evaluate Phase' AND T.PRSTATUS != 2) THEN 'End of Evaluate Phase'                       
                    WHEN (T.PRNAME = 'End of Analyse Phase' AND T.PRSTATUS != 2) THEN 'End of Analyse Phase'
                    WHEN (T.PRNAME = 'End of Design Phase' AND T.PRSTATUS != 2) THEN 'End of Design Phase'
                    WHEN (T.PRNAME = 'End of Build Phase' AND T.PRSTATUS != 2) THEN 'End of Build Phase'
                    WHEN (T.PRNAME = 'End of Test Phase' AND T.PRSTATUS != 2) THEN 'End of Test Phase'
                    WHEN (T.PRNAME = 'In Service' AND T.PRSTATUS != 2) THEN 'In Service'                    
                    WHEN (T.PRNAME = 'End of Implement Phase' AND T.PRSTATUS != 2) THEN 'End of Implement Phase'  
                    WHEN (T.PRNAME = 'End of Closure Phase' AND T.PRSTATUS != 2) THEN 'End of Closure Phase'
                    ELSE 'In Service'
               END
          AND INV_INVESTMENTS.CODE = '007058'
```

This is returning more than one row, even when the first WHEN clause is true. I thought that CASE statements finished when they found a TRUE statement.

**EDIT: Perhaps I'm not explaining this well, let's try this:**

**In each ID in the INV_INVESTMENTS table is a project. Each project has a set of tasks in the PRTASK table. In this PRTASK table, we will have the names of tasks (PRNAME), a status (PRSTATUS), and a finish date (PRFINISH). The list of tasks, in the order they occur in a project are:**

**1. Concept Tech PEP Meeting Date**
**2. Concept BRU Meeting Date**
**3. End of Concept Phase**
**4. Evaluate Tech PEP Meeting Date**
**5. Evalute BRU Meeting Date**
**6. Evaluate TSC Meeting Date**

**The rest of the tasks are in the order I have them listed in the CASE statement. What I want this query to return, is the finish date for the first task in the list with a PRSTATUS of 0 or 1.**

Comment: The `CASE` is evaluated for each row in your table(s). All rows that match the `WHERE` criteria are included in the result set. Methinks you are using the `CASE` statement wrongly. For every row with `PRSTATUS != 2 [and PNAME among those included, which appears to be all of them] OR PRNAME = 'In Service' AND INV_INVESTMENTS.CODE = '007058'` the `WHERE` clause will evaluate as TRUE, and the row returned. Perhaps if you provided sample input data and expected results, I could attempt to write the query.

Comment: @Turophile, I'm trying to return the finish date of only one of those T.PRNAMEs. While multiple can be true, only one is relevant at a time (and relevant in the order listed, i.e. Concept BRU Meeting Date becomes what I want to find once Concept Tech PEP Meeting Date has a PRSTATUS of 2, which in the database means completed). I have been trying to figure out the best way to write this logically. My logic was that if they're in order of occurrence, then I would always find the next most relevant PRNAME. I guess that's not the case.

Comment: What is PRSTATUS for?

Comment: @AlexBuyny, PRSTATUS has a value of 0 (Not Started), 1 (Started), or 2 (Completed). I was hoping to use this to move to the next relevant PRNAME in the list, as each preceding one should have a PRSTATUS of 2, and then it is no longer relevant.

Comment: @MatthewPaxman then looks like you are just interested in those with PRSTATUS = 2, I included it in my query below

Comment: @AlexBuyny, I'm interested in the first PRNAME list (in the CASE) that has a PRSTATUS of 0 or 1. If it is 2, then I want to ignore it. Basically, I want the T.PRFINISH of the first T.PRNAME in the CASE with a PRSTATUS of 0 or 1.

Comment: @MatthewPaxman I updated my query to include PRSTATUS of 0 or 1 in WHERE clause. So currently, inside "names" subselect you can define your required ordering. By joining it with your PRTASK and ordering by names.Order you will have what you need I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You can put your known names into a table, and then use it in a join. This will simplify your select to the following:

```
SELECT TOP 1 To_Char(T.PRFINISH, 'DD/MM/YY') FINISH,
       T.PRNAME  
FROM  PRTASK T
      LEFT OUTER JOIN INV_INVESTMENTS ON T.PRPROJECTID = INV_INVESTMENTS.ID
      JOIN ( 
      SELECT 'Concept Tech PEP Meeting Date' as Name, 1 as [Order]
      UNION All
      SELECT '<your next PRNAME here', 2 as [Order]
      UNION ALL ...
      ) names on names.Name = T.PRNAME
where PRSTATUS IN (0,1) AND PRINV_INVESTMENTS.CODE = '007058'
ORDER BY names.Order
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, I only have read access to the database I'm trying to query this information from, so I cannot create tables.

Comment: You can put you well-known prnames into an inner select statement as above

Comment: Took me a second to realise I needed to SELECT from DUAL (Oracle), but otherwise this worked perfectly. Thanks mate, I didn't even think of this. I was so stuck in CASE that I didn't consider another option.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand what you are trying to do (no sample data/results given) but I would restructure it like this:

```
SELECT To_Char(PRFINISH, 'DD/MM/YY') AS FINISH, PRNAME
FROM ( 
  SELECT MAX(PRFINISH),
         PRNAME  
  FROM  PRTASK AS T
  WHERE  (PRNAME = 'In Service' OR PRSTATUS != 2)
  AND    PRPROJECTID IN 
    (SELECT ID 
     FROM INV_INVESTMENTS
     WHERE CODE = '007058' )
  GROUP BY PRNAME
  ) AS TABLE1
```

Note, this is assuming that you listed all the possible values of `PRNAME` in your query.